# mongodb find docs with query over item in array

Tags: mongodb, find

I have collection in mongodb with documents like follow:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51bf000a3d489f2df59aa4c6"),
"arch" : "freebsd",
"enqueued_time" : [
    [
        NumberLong(1356985578),
        NumberLong(0)
    ]
]
 }
```

My goal is to get documents with condition: enqueued_time[1]< some_value. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want documents that the second item in array `enqueued_time` is equals `some_value` ? Or any item?

Comment: enqueued_time is the list of lists like [time1, time2]. So I want to get documents, that contains pairs [time1,time2] in enqueued_time with time2 less than some value.@MiguelCartagena

Comment: I tried to run find: db.tasks.find({$where: "this.enqueued_time[0][1] < 123"}), but can't find anything. But I'm sure that such docs exists.

Comment: Is your structure fixed to ONE array with ONE array inside? Or you queried `enqueued_time[0][1]` just for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.tasks.find({"enqueued_time.0": {$lt: your_value_here}})
```

[$lt operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/lt/)

Comment: Since he's looking for the second item, you probably want `.1`

Comment: error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: $lt", "code" : 13097 } @VladimirKurijov